# How to extract in R the key and value of a by result object?

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate

I have the following snippet that is somewhat self-explanatory:

```
> value <- by(df$Percent, df$Year, sum)
> str(value)
  'by' int [1:20(1d)] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
   ..$ df$Year: chr [1:20] "1993" "1994" "1995" "1996" ...
  - attr(*, "call")= language by.default(data = df$Percent, INDICES = df$Year, FUN = sum)
```

The question is how to extract all the keys (in this case Year) and aggregated values (all sum Percents) as a collection? I have tried many things but can't figure out how to get it e.g. in this case all the years and all the Percents.

The only way I have found is iterating and accessing it using the [[]] operator e.g. value[[1]] but this is very inefficient and inconvenient.

UPDATE: my use-case is I have the following data set e.g.

```
Year Percent
1999 40
1999 20
1999 10
2000 10
2000 20
```

and I just need the sum of percents per year i.e.

```
Year Percent
1999 70
2000 30
```

by gives me this but in an EXTREMELLY inconvenient output structure. I just need two lists or one simple output data frame.

Comment: What form do you want your final data to be in? There are *several* aggregating functions in R--maybe you're just not using the right one.

Comment: In this case, just wrap the output of `by` in `c()` and you'll get a named vector.

Comment: I would have used `tapply`: `with(df, tapply(Percent, Year, sum))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest `aggregate` for something like this (if you're sticking with base R):

```
aggregate(Percent ~ Year, mydf, sum)
#   Year Percent
# 1 1999      70
# 2 2000      30
```

`tapply` is also a reasonable choice:

```
with(mydf, tapply(Percent, Year, sum))
# 1999 2000 
#   70   30
```

This is the same as what you would get with `by` if you wrapped it in `c()`:

```
c(with(mydf, by(Percent, Year, sum)))
# 1999 2000 
#   70   30
```

In the case of both `by` and `tapply`, here, you get a named vector, while with `aggregate`, you get a `data.frame`.

---

Other convenient options include "data.table" and "plyr"/"dplyr".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, list(Percent = sum(Percent)), by = Year]

library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(Percent = sum(Percent))
```

The "plyr" option can be found in the other answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `plyr` for these types of problems.

#### 1. generate data

```
n= 10
df<-data.frame(id=1:n,percent=runif(n=n,min=0,max=.2),
    Year=sample(x=seq(2010,2012),replace=T,size=n))
```

#### 2. Summarize w plyr

```
library(plyr)
df.sum <- ddply(df,
                   .(Year), summarise, 
                   percent = sum(percent),
                   count = length(Year) 
)
```

The `count` line can be omitted--I usually include to see how many records went into the summary.

```
> df.sum
  year    percent count
1 2010 0.53990719     4
2 2011 0.06252893     2
3 2012 0.41634975     4
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use @ako's data and change your call to `by` to reflect the slightly different naming:

```
> value <- by(df$percent, df$Year, sum)
>  str(value)
 by [1:3(1d)] 0.586 0.112 0.289
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ df$Year: chr [1:3] "2010" "2011" "2012"
 - attr(*, "call")= language by.default(data = df$percent, INDICES = df$Year, FUN = sum)
> attr(value, 'df$Year')
NULL
> attr(value, 'dimnames')
$`df$Year`
[1] "2010" "2011" "2012"
```

The str result is telling you that the "rownames"-so-to-speak of the `by`-result is stored in an attribute named `dimnames`. Attributes are generally stored as lists and this one has an odd name that looks like a function call to '$' so it would require quoting that name if all you wanted were the values in the list:

```
> attr(value, 'dimnames')[['df$Year']]
[1] "2010" "2011" "2012"
```

So I guess the question is whether you are required to use `by`? I will add that people often use `do.call(rbind, ...)` on the results of a by-operations to produce more useful values:

```
> bval <- do.call(rbind, as.list(value))
> bval
          [,1]
2010 0.5863529
2011 0.1121907
2012 0.2887475
```